# How can I reload images on a main page after uploading images to a form in the sub page?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am using Tutor LMS with WordPress. There is a dashboard page and it has sub pages. I have a sub page called My Organization that allows the user to update a form and also upload a logo and backdrop image. The logo and backdrop are the images used for the main dashboard page and shows on top for all sub pages.

The good thing is that if I update the form fields and hit the update button, it will refresh and then the fields will be updated thereafter (got some major help for that one). The dingy thing is that the logo and backdrop don't update unless I refresh again.

Here is a screen [recording](https://streamable.com/2s3oqm)

I have been looking for a fix but I can't seem to find anything. I tried using

```
<script>
    window.opener.location.reload();
</script>
```

but it did not work.

Please let me know if you have a lead!

Here is my code for the subpage called My Organization:

```
<?php

global $wpdb;

$user_id  = get_current_user_id();
$org_id = get_user_meta($user_id, '_org_id', true);

if (isset($_POST['update']) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['logo_url_nonce'], 'logo_url' ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['backdrop_url_nonce'], 'backdrop_url' )) {
    
    $orgs = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM `wp_organization` WHERE id = $org_id"));
    
    $user_org = null;
    foreach($orgs as $org) {
    $user_org = $org;
    }
    
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
    
    if ($_FILES['logo_url']['size'] > 0) {
    $logo_attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'logo_url', $_POST['post_id']);
    $logo_url = wp_get_attachment_url($logo_attachment_id);
    } else {
        $logo_url = $user_org->logo_url;
    }
    
    if ($_FILES['backdrop_url']['size'] > 0) {
    $backdrop_attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'backdrop_url', $_POST['post_id']);
    $backdrop_url = wp_get_attachment_url($backdrop_attachment_id);
    } else {
        $backdrop_url = $user_org->backdrop_url;
    }
    
    $name = isset($_POST['org_name']) ? $_POST['org_name'] : "";
    $short = isset($_POST['shortname']) ? $_POST['shortname'] : "";
    $ind = isset($_POST['industry']) ? $_POST['industry'] : "";
    $desc = isset($_POST['description']) ? $_POST['description'] : "";
    $logo = isset($_FILES['logo_url']) ? $logo_url : "";
    $backdrop = isset($_FILES['backdrop_url']) ? $backdrop_url : "";

    $wpdb->query(
        $wpdb->prepare("
        UPDATE `wp_organization` SET         
            name = %s,
            shortname = %s,
            industry = %s,
            description = %s,
            logo_url = %s,
            backdrop_url = %s
            where id = %s 
        ",
            $name, $short, $ind, $desc, $logo, $backdrop, $org_id
        )
    );

$orgs = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM `wp_organization` WHERE id = $org_id"));

$user_org = null;
foreach($orgs as $org) {
    $user_org = $org;
}

?>
<!-- organization info form -->
<div class="tutor-px-20">
<form class="py-4 col-md-6 mx-auto" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="d-flex tutor-justify-center tutor-fs-3 tutor-fw-bold tutor-mb-20">
Organization Information
</div>

<div class="tutor-form-group">
<label class="tutor-form-label">Name</label>
<input type="text" required name="org_name" value="<?php echo $user_org-> name; ?>" class="form-control mb-3" />
</div>

<div class="tutor-form-group">
<label class="tutor-form-label">Industry</label>
<input type="text" name="industry" value="<?php echo $user_org-> industry; ?>" class="form-control mb-3" />
</div>

<div class="tutor-form-group">
<label class="tutor-form-label">Short name (4 characters)</label>
<input type="text" name="shortname" required maxlength="4" value="<?php echo $user_org-> shortname; ?>" class="form-control mb-3" />
</div>

<div class="tutor-form-group">
<label class="tutor-form-label">Description</label>
<textarea class="form-control mb-3" name="description" rows="5" cols="50"><?php echo trim(stripslashes($user_org-> description)); ?></textarea>
</div>

<div class="d-flex tutor-justify-around">
<div class="tutor-form-group">
<label class="tutor-form-label">Logo (Size: 200x200px Limit: 200kb)</label>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="file" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg" name="logo_url" id="logo_url" multiple="false">
    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="<?php echo get_the_ID()?>"/>
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'logo_url', 'logo_url_nonce' ); ?>
</div>
</div>

<div class="tutor-form-group">
<label class="tutor-form-label">Backdrop (Size: 1140x275px Limit: 600kb)</label>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="file" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg" name="backdrop_url" id="backdrop_url" multiple="false">
    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="<?php echo get_the_ID()?>"/>
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'backdrop_url', 'backdrop_url_nonce' ); ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="tutor-mt-32 d-flex tutor-justify-center">
    <input type="submit" name="update" value='Update' class='btn btn-primary'>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

The images are used in the main page called Dashboard and here is a snip of the code:

```
<div class="tutor-wrap tutor-wrap-parent tutor-dashboard tutor-frontend-dashboard tutor-dashboard-student tutor-mt-80 tutor-pb-40">
        <div class="tutor-container" >
       <?php if($org_id) { ?>
        <div class="tutor-row tutor-d-flex tutor-justify-between tutor-mb-20" 
        style="background-image: url('<?php echo $user_org->backdrop_url; ?>'); background-size: auto; height:275px; border-radius: 20px;">
        <div class="tutor-d-flex tutor-justify-center tutor-mb-60 ">
        <div class="tutor-avatar tutor-avatar-xl" style="width:150px; height:150px; position: absolute; top:155px">
        <img src="<?php echo $user_org->logo_url; ?>">
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add an "id" to the div containing the image (and background). Then using ajax to push the code snip again.

Build a little example, not perfect, but should give you an idea. You can pass data to another php page, do stuff and return the data in JSON to work on it.

Note : Make sure you do thing securely (aka, use sessions to pass critical data, else someone could pass other data and get informations from other users).

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="logo"><img src="loading.jpg" /></div>
    <script>
      function UpdateLogo() {
        $.ajax({
          url: "ajax.php",
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            action: "updateLogo",
          },
          success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (response["STATUS"] == "OK") {
              $("#logo").html('<img src="' + response["logo"] + '">');
            }
          },
          error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $("#logo").html("Error;" + errorThrown);
          },
        });
      }
      UpdateLogo();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php

if ($action = "UpdateLogo") {
    //do stuff using sessions variable or whatever secure.
    $return['STATUS'] = 'OK';
    $return['logo'] = 'bla.jpg';
    echo json_encode($return);
}
```